# Any Maintained Libraries for Node.JS to use Amazon SES (Email Service)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I realize there are a few posts on this already but most of the libraries that are mentioned are at least a year old (and don't have a lot of features such as attachment support, checking bouncebacks, etc).

Does anybody know the best library for Node.js to use Amazon SES that is maintained?

Ex:

- [node-amazon-ses](https://github.com/jjenkins/node-amazon-ses) No attachment support; no callback for if the send for successful. But it does have

  - DeleteVerifiedEmailAddress
  - GetSendQuota
  - GetSendStatistics
  - ListVerifiedEmailAddresses
  - SendEmail
  - VerifyEmailAddress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS SDK for Node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs) supports SES.

Comment: Nice find! Definitely nice that it's straight from Amazon. But I can't seem to figure out how to attach file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES/Client.html#sendEmail-property

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the node mailer module which can be used with SES: 
https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Here is an example with SES and attachments: 
https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/blob/master/examples/example_ses.js

Not really a full featured SES library, but does make sending to ses with attachments simpler.